# how to solve the problem: pscp: unable to open /home/cse316/lab1.rar: permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, window, pscp

I have connected to the two computers. One system is windows, another is ubuntu. And I want to send a lab.rar file to the ubuntu from windows by using the software **pscp(putty)** .

Here is my command to send the file (windows system):

```
D:\>pscp C:\Users\Tyler.Tuo\Desktop\lab1.rar ubuntu@192.168.0.109:/home/cse316
```

However, it reports error like this:

```
pscp: unable to open /home/cse316/lab1.rar: permission denied
```

It seems I have no permission to visit the location in ubuntu system. 
How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution , open your Ubuntu system and type this: `sudo chmod 777 -R /home/cse316`

Comment: Thanks! The problem has fixed

Comment: Bad advice though...

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to keep in mind is that all directories before the targeted one MUST HAVE the execution right (chmod +x ...)

For example, if the target folder is `/apps/ubuntu/data`, the following must have the execution right :

- /apps
- /apps/ubuntu

In addition, giving 777 right is a VERY BAD PRACTISE

Only `wx` are necessary to give access a user to create files, and `rx` to read them

Then, please, set your rights correctly in order to avoid security issues